# Query to get the rank of a word embedded in a text of a XML file

Tags: xml, get, rank

I am working on extracting parts of an XML file.

I need to get the rank value of “Vdepth” (that is “2”).

The XML file code is as follows:

```
<logData>
  <mnemonicList>Mdepth,Vdepth,Bit Dist,TQ on btm</mnemonicList> 
</logData>
```

`//logData/mnemonicList/text()` provides the all text, since `text()` is not a function but a node test.
`(//logData/mnemonicList/text())[2]` returns a “NO MATCH!”.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for an expression that evaluates to `Vdepth` or to `2`?

Comment: I am looking for an expression that provides the rank value of ´Vdepth´. 2 is expected to be the answer. The same would stand for Bit Dist (3 being the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following xpath expressions (if available to you):

```
index-of(tokenize(//mnemonicList,','),'Vdepth')
index-of(tokenize(//mnemonicList,','),'Bit Dist')
```

you get `2` and `3`, respectively.